# scipy.odr fails in fitting exponential function

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm working on an astrophysics project where I need to measure the density(ne) of the gas in the center of the galaxy by two methods(A and S). I made a plot of ne_s x ne_a and I want to try an exponential fit in this plot. The problems are the following:

1. the errors in the data are asymmetrical and, apparently, scipy.odr does not accept this type of error. When the erros are included 'ValueError: could not convert we to a suitable array' is raised.
2. even if I do not include the errors the fit still does not work.

The code used(errors in the fit not included):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ne_s = np.array([ 134.70722125,  316.27850769,  403.37221974,  579.91067991,
                1103.06258335, 1147.23685549,  115.00820933,  476.42659337,
                667.61690967,  403.30988606,  282.08007264,  479.98058352,
                897.64247885,  214.75999934,  213.22512064,  491.81749573,
                743.68513419,  374.37957281,  362.136037  ,  893.88595455])

dne_s_max = np.array([23.6619623 ,  5.85802097, 12.02456923,  1.50211648,  5.15987014,
                    10.3830146 , 10.5274528 ,  0.82928872,  2.18586603, 31.95014727,
                    6.53134179,  2.38392559, 32.2838402 ,  5.43629034,  1.02316579,
                    6.60281602, 14.53943481,  9.16809221,  6.84052648, 12.87655997])

dne_s_min = np.array([21.94513608,  5.80578938, 11.8303456 ,  1.49856527,  5.1265976 ,
                    10.2523836 , 10.12663739,  0.82824884,  2.17914616, 30.55846643,
                    6.45691351,  2.37446669, 30.87025015,  5.37271061,  1.02087355,
                    6.5358395 , 14.21332643,  9.0523711 ,  6.77187898, 12.64596461])

ne_a = np.array([  890.61498788,  2872.03715706, 10222.33463389,  1946.48193766,
                    6695.25304235,  2107.36471192,   891.72010662,  3988.87511761,
                    11328.9670489 ,  1097.38904905,  2896.62668843,  4849.57809801,
                    5615.96780935,  1415.18564794,  1204.00022768,  3616.05423907,
                    15638.52683391,  3300.6039601 ,   775.28841051, 12325.54379524])

dne_a_max = np.array([1082.33639266,  571.57094375, 2396.39839075,  458.32058555,
                    796.79916236,  665.95370946, 2262.73423374, 1006.65192577,
                    1761.9251987 , 1718.78400914,  579.65477159,  245.54811362,
                    1652.50314639,  401.37677822,  178.03620792,  725.26490794,
                    6625.62353545,  908.21490446,  719.01117673, 2098.24809312])

dne_a_min = np.array([ 865.33019015,  518.08880981, 1877.85283954,  412.91242092,
                        724.38681574,  582.52644162,  870.14392196,  866.63643893,
                        1478.1792513 , 1076.64135559,  521.08794554,  236.2457763 ,
                        1349.36104495,  362.72343267,  169.23314057,  646.39803115,
                        4139.5768453 ,  789.04878324,  620.55523654, 1720.06369942])
dne_a = [dne_a_min, dne_a_max]
dne_s = [dne_s_min, dne_s_max]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.errorbar(ne_s, ne_a, xerr = dne_s, yerr = dne_a,
            linestyle = 'none', linewidth = 0.7, capsize = 5, color = 'crimson')
ax.scatter(ne_s, ne_a, s = 15, color = 'black')
ax.set_ylabel('$n_e(A)$'), ax.set_xlabel('$n_e(S)$')

from scipy.odr import Data, RealData, Model, ODR

def f(B, x):
    return B[0] + B[1] * np.exp(B[2] * x)

exponential = Model(f)
data = RealData(ne_s, ne_a)
odr = ODR(data, exponential, beta0=[1, 200, 3e-3])
out = odr.run()

ax.plot(ne_s, f(out.beta, ne_s), linewidth = 0.7)
```

Which results in:

[image: ne_s_x_ne_a_fit]

And the actual plot is:

[image: ne_s_x_ne_a]

So what am I missing here? Did I applied the odr routine erroneously? What should I do to make the fit work properly? And how to make scipy.odr accept asymmetrical error?

Important to add that I don't know too much about scipy.odr, I just adapted the documentation example to an exponential function.

Appreciate the help. Let me know if more information is necessary.

Comment: According to the documentation you can specify either a weight or an error but not an asymmetric error.  I have not read it it detail, but it looks that this might be useful: https://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C030908/papers/WEMT002.pdf

Comment: I didn't understand the text very well, but I'll show it to my advisor as working with these asymmetric errors has led me to a lot of extra work.